# XUnit best way to test void methods

Tags: c#, xunit

I'm trying to write an unit test in **XUnit** to test a void method.
What are some best practices to do this in XUnit?

So far, I've tried to catch some exceptions with `Assert.Throws()` but I'm just adding exceptions for the sake of making my unit test work.

Pseudo code of a method I'd like to test:

```
public void SendCheckInReminder()
{
  - Get employees and checkins from database
  - Check if employees are not null and if last check-in is older than three months
  - If so: send email using my mailservice
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) That code should likely be an `async Task`. 2) The "database" and "mailservice" dependencies should be injected. 3) Mock the database and mail services. 4) Test whether the mocks were invoked or not based on the business requirement.

Comment: You test return values (which you don't have), look for exceptions (which you probably should have) and side effects (which you **do** have). For side effects, I would probably want to know if methods had been called on the mail service for example. Hopefully you injected that as an interface into this object you are testing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.